# jupyter notebookでのplt.show()について

Tags: jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebookで，セル１~３のそれぞれにグラフを出力するコードが書かれていて，セル１の末尾にplt.show()と書くと，全てのセルのグラフが三枚ずつ出てきたのですがなぜですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythonのmatplotlibをjupyter notebookを使用してのことでしょうか？
コードを確認しないと詳細はわかりませんが、jupyter notebookはセルの実行順にも影響があります。セル１~３実行してから、セル１実行すると前の結果が表示されます。
もしよろしければ、コードを記載してください。